# How can I resolve Django class serializer assertion Error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Trying to work with Django Rest Framework when I run the code I get an error on

`Error message: Class MovieSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute`

Here are my Serializers below

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    models = Movie
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')



class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        models = Rating
        fields = ('id', 'movie', 'stars', 'user')
```

I legit do not know where the error could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be ‘model’ not ‘models’ in meta.

Comment: Oh my goodness I cant believe and I overlooked that, thanks man its now working perfectly well